# Getting a slightly wrong array from my function, only differs by a comma however not any value or no. of values

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

```
A = [[2, 3, 5, -6],[10, 41, -3, 7],[12.5, -8, 16, 15],[10.5, 15.5, 20, -13]]
B = [60,80,100,200]
def solveLEs(A,B):
    X=np.linalg.solve(A,B)
    Y=np.sum(X)
    W=X, Y
    Z=np.array(W)
    return Z
print(solveLEs(A,B))
```

this gives me the output of:

```
[array([22.03381014, -2.4303291 , -4.80024007, -7.87076123])
 6.9324797439231745]
```

which is correct, however, on the checker for this code it requires the solution to have a comma inbetween the array and the sum

Comment: Instead of `W=X, Y`, just `return [X, Y]`. No need to put it in a `np.array`

Comment: cheers this solved it